# Openxml sdk. How to Search, Read and Replace text in paragraph with image

Tags: image, search, sdk, replace, openxml

I'm generating Word(.docx) document and experiencing an issue of how to insert diagrams, images instead of custom tags in document that are already there. But initially I create document from several .RTF files, using "Altchunk" approach, inserting .RTFs into content controls in template doc. Those .RTF files contain our custom tags, they look like "<ElementType="Diagram" Name="Somename">" and appear in document just with the new line like shown below.(And we don't know, in advance, how many those tags will be in doc)
.......

<ElementType="Diagram" Name="Some name of the diagram">

.......
Googled it but can't find good approach of how to replace tags with images.
Because first I need to read tag in order to recognize the name of image, so I know what image will go instead of tag, then remove tag(just text) from document and on its place put an image I just fetched, knowing the name of the image. So it is pretty complicated, but I hope someone have good ideas to share. Thanks

I would like to describe this issue a little bit more specific:

1) Regarding *altchunk* method, I just find content controls which I put in word document that I use as template, and when I have rtf string, I insert altchunk after that CC.
my method looks like the following:

```
    private void ReplaceContentControlWithRTF(MainDocumentPart mainPart, string tagName,     string rtfString) 
{
                SdtBlock sb = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val == tagName).Single();
                string altChunkId = "altChunkId" + altChunkIdNumber++;
                AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Rtf, altChunkId);
                MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rtfString));
                chunk.FeedData(s);
                AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
                altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement parent = sb.Parent;
                parent.InsertAfter(altChunk, sb);
                sb.Remove();
                mainPart.Document.Save();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer got quite long, so I'll separate the contents with some headings in order to make it easier to read :). You should consider each of them unless you already found a better approach.

**Concatenating documents**

I suppose that when you use *altchunk* method, you have then an xml of the first document (an original one) and all appended documents are encoded.
Better approach would be to concatenate contents of documents, because you have then easy access to the xml tree of the whole document. It's quite easy if you don't use images, hyperlinks etc. in concatenated documents, because they need to be handled in a special way and can make it more complicated.

Alternatively, you can try to insert images to each of the document BEFORE concatenating them.

**Use Content Controls as placeholders in the document**

Now, supposing you already can access document, you should place Content Controls in Word documents, in places you want your images to appear and set *Tag* of each of them to a value you should then search in your code in order to find the right place to insert the picture. You can find some basic information about Content Controls here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/content-controls-HA010030750.aspx.

**Insert XML tags and image's bytes**

In order to insert an image to a document, you have not only to insert some XML tags in a place you want the image to appear, but also add bytes containing the image as an `ImagePart`. I've found a tutorial explaning how to do it here (although I haven't followed it myself):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342530%28v=office.12%29.aspx.

**Consider using OpenXML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool**

In order to make your work with OpenXML SDK simpler, I recommend you to use SDK Productivity Tool from Microsoft. It can be donwloaded as a part of the OpenXML SDK and it allows you to open any MS Office OpenXML document, show its contents in XML manner and can even display C# code required to recreate it. You can download it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124.

If you have any other questions, feel free to ask :).

Comment: "Use Content Controls as placeholders in the document", yes it would be nice to know where my images will appear, but this document is supposed to be generated many times with different input data(rtf files), so I can't know how many and where images will be placed. But when I have inserted all the rtf files, I have .docx file with custom tags that look like just text in new paragraph <ElementType="Diagram" Name="SomeName">. So I have to find them, read, and replace by matching image(I have read its name).

Comment: So I'm not sure what your problem is. You have to do it as you described in the question ;). Read tutorial on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342530%28v=office.12%29.aspx. It explains how to insert an image into a document. BAsically, when you find your custom tag, remove it, get parent pagargaph node and insert an image tag there as well as insert image part into the document. I suppose the link contains quite detailed instructions explaining how to insert images.

Comment: Almost done with this, but will you give the last clue regarding how to get width of usable space of the page ? I guess it will be in some units, not in pixels.

Comment: It would be helpful if you give some more information about it. If it's a constant size that you want to determine, I would recommend you to use Open XML SDK Productivity Tool. If you want to put an image in that space, do it with Word, save the document and then open it in the tool and check what size is used there :).

Comment: It is ok with page width now.But when I have inserted in template doc all the .rtf files using altchunk method above.I need to go through all the paragraphs.And here strange things go.I use the following line - "foreach (Paragraph p in mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>())" but it actually works only, if I do update table of contents before,if not,I dont get all the paragraphs actually, seems no paragraphs with text inserted from .RTFs. When I open target doc with Word(not fully completed), I see all the text from RTFs.Strange.Have I forgotten something to call before foreach loop?

Comment: It seems there is a bug in altchunk approach, will come back when resolved.

Comment: No, it's rather not a bug. As I've written in the answer, if you use altchunk method, you probably get xml structure of your first document only (the one to which you appended the others). Documents appended are saved within the resulting file in encoded form (I suppose it's base64 string). In resolve issue with this you can concatenate them manually OR trying to use a workaround: edit each of the files BEFORE concatenating them and concatenate them after all the paragraphs are modified.